# Minimal Django example to execute a Python code to the uploaded file and display the result

Tags: python, html, django

I want to build a web application using Django.
These are the flow I'm planning to execute:

- Page1 - User select execution mode from drop down list.
- Page2 - Make an upload page according to chosen execution mode.
         In this page user can: upload, choose parameter, and press execute button.
- Page3 - We execute the Python code, via a function of a self-made Python module. The result is a JSON file. While waiting for this to finish, we display
  a JavaScript waiting bar.
- Page4 - When the JSON output file is ready we display the result with a self-made Javascript code.

Through out this process, using Unix JOBID we create a subdirectory for each job submitted.

This is my first experience with Django. Please advice what's the minimum code needed to create this framework?

Comment: You should start the project and come back with a more specific (and answerable) question.

Comment: use the django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) as a starting point and modify as needed.